# ContentObserver for Camera Button?

Tags: android, camera, contentobserver

I have tried to detect when camera button is pressed using Broadcastreceiver but it doesn't work, and I don't understand why (maybe my phone is the problem). Now, I want to know if is it possible to do this using ContentObserver. Is possible? If yes, can you give me an example...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

`BroadcastReceiver`, not `ContentObserver`.

```
<receiver android:name=".CameraButtonBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You should implement `CameraButtonBroadcastReceiver` class, which is a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: I have done this but it is not working...for that I'm trying to find something else for doing this...:(

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% positive on this but the camera button might be one of those intent that cannot be declared in the manifest. Try registering it in a service and see if that works